# Cannot Load style in Vue when publish to npm

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli3 to publish a vue component to npm.

Here is my build scripts:

```json
"package-build": "eclint fix && vue-cli-service build --target lib --name @xchat-component/chat-component ./src/index.ts && shx cp ./src/index.d.ts dist/index.d.ts",
```

When I import this component in other projects, all functions are normal, but the style is not working.

But I found that css is in `node_modules/component/dist/component.css`

[image: css]

Is there any solution to this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem!

First, you need to create vue.config.js in the vue component project and add the following code.

```
module.exports = {
  css: { extract: false },
};
```

Then, you need to move the css part in vue to `../assets/css/style.css` and import `../assets/css/style.css` like below:

```
<style scoped src="../assets/css/style.css">
</style>
```

After package and publish, the component can read the CSS normally!